# mapbox annotation 0.9.0 not work with mapbox 9.6.0

Tags: android, annotations, mapbox

I added mapbox and its annotation dependency like below:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0'
api 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0'
```

every things worked well, but since I have changed mapbox version from 9.2.0 to 9.6.0 got this error when run my app.
Attention: Build is successful, but app not run correctly. Also this error occurs with v9.4.0 and 9.5.0.

Error:

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :mapir-android-sdk
   > Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :mapir-android-sdk > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Mapbox Maps SDK for Android version 9.4, the way to access the Maven repository to download the SDK libraries has changed.

You now need to create a secret access token and use it to access the maven repo, where the libraries are located. Your module level build.gradle should contain this:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
      authentication {
          basic(BasicAuthentication)
      }
      credentials {
        // Do not change the username below.
        // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
          username = 'mapbox'
          // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
          password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please also see:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/#configure-credentials

Comment: I did what you say, but my mistake that was I put credential in :app gradle file because i don't want force user to create mapbox account, actually i use mapbox in my custom package. Thank you for response.

Comment: @mortezahosseini i had the same issue, any solution about this topic?